# Initializing a pointer in another class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a very simple problem. I am trying to learn C++ and I'm having a little problem. Here's the code

system.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "processor.h"
using namespace std;

class sys
{
    public:
        int id;
        sys()
        {
            id=0;
        }
};
```

processor.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class proc
{
    public:
    const sys* s1;
    s1=new sys();
};
```

The error says

```
"error C2512: 'sys' : no appropriate default constructor available"
```

There is a default constructor.

I am a beginner at C++ so please explain what I am doing wrong. Thank You.

Comment: You really don't want to have a global `using namespace` directives in header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You do not initialize class members inside the class body, You do so in the class constructor.
- `const` members are special members and they **must** be initialized in the **[Member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**.
- Avoid using dynamically allocated memory as much as possible and if you must use **smart pointers** instead of raw pointers.

---

```
proc() : s1(new sys())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since class `proc` is using class `sys` the include order should be the opposite:

```
// sys.h
class sys {
   ...
};

// process.h
#include "sys.h"

class proc {
   ...
};
```